# MySQL + PHP: Problemas con "mysqli_query(): Empty query in"

Tags: php, mysqli, sql

Primero os pondré en contexto: Tengo una aplicación web que pide a un Usuario que inserte un archivo SQL. Una vez el usuario lo ha importado, el código PHP **te envía a otra página PHP** y desde ahí, ejecuta el contenido del SQL y realiza las consultas del archivo a una Base de datos MySQL.

Todo esto se realiza correctamente, ya que desde otra ventana puedo ver que los cambios se han efectuado. Pero cuando quiero que vuelva a la página anterior, no me hace la función de redirección debido al siguiente error:

[image: Imagen_Error]

He buscado por Stack Overflow y se ve que puede ser un error de Sintaxis de la query y está me la devuelve vacía.

Os pongo aquí partes del código:

- El archivo SQL ( es el que insertará el usuario en la anterior página ):

  INSERT INTO tipostec (tiposTec_id, tiposTec_tipus) VALUES( NULL, 'Nombre_Tecnologia' );
  INSERT INTO tipostec (tiposTec_id, tiposTec_tipus) VALUES( NULL, 'Nombre_Tecnologia2' );
- El código PHP que da error ( $arrayRA es el array del nombre del archivo que envío ):

  ```
          if(strlen($arrayRA) != 0 ){

              $target_dir = '';
              $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['archivo']['name']);
              $uploadOk = 1;
              $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

              //Solo aceptará los archivos con el formato en SQL:
              if($imageFileType != 'sql') {
                  //echo "alert(\"Lo sentimos pero, solo están permitidos los archivos SQL.\");";
                  $uploadOk = 0;
              }

              //Miramos por si acaso ha dado algún error:
              if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                  //echo "alert(\"Lo sentimos, tu archivo no se ha podido subir.\");";

              //Sí todo está bien, sube el archivo y realiza la ejecución del contenido:
              } else {
                  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
                      //echo "alert(\"El archivo ". basename( $_FILES["archivo"]["name"]). " se ha subido.\");";

                      //Encontramos el archivo en questión, revisamos su contenido línea a línea por cada ';' y ejecutamos en SQL estas filas:  
                      $handle = fopen('../'.$target_file,'r+');
                      $contents = fread($handle,filesize('../'.$target_file));

                      $sql1 = explode(';',$contents);

                      foreach($sql1 as $query){

                          $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); //mysqli_query($mysqli,$query); //$mysqli->query($query);
                          if($result){
                              //echo '<tr><td><br></td></tr>';
                              //echo '<tr><td>'.$query.'<b>SUCCESS</b></td></tr>';
                              //echo '<tr><td><br></td></tr>';

                              //echo "alert(\"Consulta ejecutada.\");";
                          }

                      }
                      fclose($handle);
                      //echo "alert(\"Successfully imported\");";


                  } else {
                      //echo "alert(\"Lo sentimos, se ha producido un error.\");";
                  }
              }
  ```
- Tablas del MySQL ( la id es AutoIncremental, por eso sale la id de 54, 55 ):

[image: TablasMySQL]

Después de todo esto, **mis preguntas son**: ¿Cual es el motivo de la aparición de este Warinig y hay algún modo para ignorar-lo? ¿Esto es un problema de la query en sí o de la función en general? ¿Podría hacer otra función de redirección aunque me salga el Warning?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

PD: La línea IMPORTANTE es --> $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

PPD: Ahora me devuelve esto ( mirar primer comentario para poner-se al día ):

[image: Error2]

- He añadido esto: 
  [image: CodigoPHP2]

Comment: He estado revisando las consultas que hace en el "foreach" y he modificado el codigo para que devuelva las querys sin \n y sigue dandome el mismo Error. Aunque ahora passa las querys sin espacios.

Comment: Veo que insertas NULL en la llave tiposTec_id. Debes de hacer esa columna autoincremental para no insertar NULL

Comment: Si, de hecho es AI y por eso le pongo NULL; para que en la tabla de MySQL se añada el siguiente id automaticamente.